# Finding 'first occurrence' using Match Function in R

Tags: r, match

I am new to 'R' and 'Stackoverflow' so forgive me for the incredibly basic question. I'm trying to find the 'index' of the first female in my dataset.

[Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLBOL.jpg)

My overall dataset is called 'bike', so first I thought it would be a good idea to assign a new vector of just the genders...

```
bike$genders
```

Then I tried using the function:

```
match(1, genders)
match(F, genders)
```

Neither of which worked! I know this is and should be relatively simple but I'm just starting out so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `which.max(bike$genders == "F")` would give the index of the first `"F"` in the `genders` column of `bike`

Comment: If genders is coded with `"M"` and `"F"`, then your problem is that `F` means `FALSE`, but `"F"` is the string F. Use `match("F", bike$genders)` and it should work fine.

Comment: @RichScriven  But which.max could be a problem, if it doesn't find the value it gives 1. Other options such as which()[1] or match give NA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most direct method would be to use
`match("F", bike[,"genders"]` which will return the index of the first match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the rows#, this should give you the rows, with their numbers printed to the screen, and you will see the index for rows with it.

`bike[bike$gender=="F",]`

and if you only want the row numbers to set to a vector
`rnam<-row.names(bike[bike$gender=="F",])`